# Uncaught TypeError: NaN JavaScript SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have developed a JavaScript countdown timer; also I have a SharePoint list that retrieves the minutes for countdown and its column name is `Koha`

I am retrieving `Koha` and initializing in  a variable; But when I try running the app the countdown timer shows me NaN?

This is how I am retrieving `Koha` field:

```
    function Retrieve(){
    currentQuizItem = quizList.getItemById(quizID);
    var quizName;
    context.load(currentQuizItem);

    var koha = currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["koha"];

    //even if I try to convert it to number it does not work
    koha = parseInt(Koha);

    alert(koha); // here I can see my value but later when I initialize this var to countdown it says NaN;

}
```

This is my JavaScript countdown timer

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
    }
 }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
   var fiveSec = 60 * koha,   //If I make this 60 * 20 it works and there are 20 min to countdown
   display = document.querySelector('#UItimer');

  startTimer(fiveSec, display);
};
```

Now when I run my app if shown me NaN:NaN instead of showing me timer

please help me

Comment: Same thing you are missing again `executeQueryAsync()`

Comment: where I have to place executeQueryAsync() now?

Comment: I have Added executeQueryAsync() just like you did un my previous question but still getting the error `NaN:NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to run `executeQueryAsync` after `context.load`

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

**[Update]**

This issue is related to `window.onload = function () {` the So the field `koha` is `empty` when you execute it `onload function`, you should start the calculate of `fevsec` after you got `kohe` value.

Comment: I placed the function() but still getting NaN:NaN but If I alert(koha) it shows me the value i.e 45 in my case

Comment: try to alert also fiveSec and check its value  may be the issue not related to code now and related to display variable display = document.querySelector('#UItimer'); , Are you tried to show it manually without retrieving from list , is it worked properly ?!

Comment: #UItimer displays the fivesec; i am retrieving the item but still can't make it to work I can share my code to you if you want

Comment: share the code and please invite me to chat room to check it

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43505/room-for-nderon-hyseni-and-m-qassas this is our conversation

Comment: Thank you so much now it is working perfectly thanks mate